# perl expression meaning for statement $a &&= ;

Tags: perl

Recently I came across this Perl expression on a  blog, unable to grab it purpose.

```
    my $success = 1; 
    $success &&= $insert_handle->execute($first, $last, $department); 
    $success &&= $update_handle->execute($department);
```

Comment: I tried a small script for the speculation $i=0,$a=1; $a &&=$i; print "$a : $i";

Comment: In short, this is a wordy way of running a bunch of steps until the first one fails, then stopping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
EXPR1 &&= EXPR2;
```

is short for

```
EXPR1 = EXPR1 && EXPR2;
```

(Except that `EXPR1` is only evaluated once.*)

The provided code

```
my $success = 1; 
$success &&= $insert_handle->execute($first, $last, $department); 
$success &&= $update_handle->execute($department);
```

could also have been written as:

```
my $success = 0;
if ($insert_handle->execute($first, $last, $department)) {
   if ($update_handle->execute($department)) {
      $success = 1;
   }
}
```

or

```
my $success = $insert_handle->execute($first, $last, $department)
           && $update_handle->execute($department);
```

---

* — This matters if `EXPR1` has side-effects, which could very well happen if it's a magical variable or an lvalue sub.

```
my $x = 3;      # Prints:
print("$x\n");  # 3

sub x() :lvalue { print("x\n"); $x }

x &&= 4;        # x
print("$x\n");  # 4

x = x && 5;     # x x
print("$x\n");  # 5
```

Comment: Because the && operator evaluates the right operand and returns the result when the left operand evaluates to true.

Comment: It evaluates the LHS operand first. If it's true, it evaluates the RHS operand and assigns the result to the variable previously returned by the LHS.

Answer (score 3):

It is a long way of saying.

```
 my $success =
     $insert_handle->execute($first, $last, $department)
     && $update_handle->execute($department);
```

Comment: +1 on your statement, but I think the original coder was expecting to have a long series of method calls and wanted them to all look the same on the page, thus the initial setting of $success.  That way calls can be inserted before the given first call without changing anything.  In fact, the OP may be just showing us the first couple of lines of method calls.

Comment: Yes, could be. Though it's still possible to do it like `1 && .. && .. && ...`. But, anyway, what I was trying to do is to explain the meaning in simple expression, not recommend a replacement. It's up to every coder to decide how he expresses him or her-self ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Might be : -

```
my $success = 1; 
$success = $success && $insert_handle->execute($first, $last, $department); 
$success = $success && $update_handle->execute($department);
```

Similar to : -

```
a += b  
// is equivalent to
a = a + b
```